# How to set underline text of UIButton (which has custom localisation in Xcode 6.3)?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uibutton

I know that this question is asked many times, but the most answers are several years ago. I hope there there is a easiest solution for `Xcode 6.3`.

I have `UIViewController` in which I have 2 buttons which must be underlined. I also use custom solution for translating resources (my language is set inside the App - according the specification).

I see that I can set attributed text in `Xcode 6.3`, but in that case the text in the button (resource) is not translated.

I tried to set `NSMutableAttributedString` as text, but the `setTitle` method needs NSString and I have error.

I see that there are answers with making custom button type, but I think this is a bit complex (I have those two buttons only in the UIViewController).

Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to set NSMutableAttributedString as text, but the setTitle method needs NSString and I have error.

Because you are calling the wrong method. You want the `setAttributedTitle:forState:` method, which solves that problem.

> I see that I can set attributed text in Xcode 6.3, but in that case the text in the button (resource) is not translated.

Set the attributed text *in code*, by calling `setAttributedTitle:forState:`, starting with a string that is defined *in code*. When you define that string, call NSLocalizedString. Define the localized string in a *Localizable.strings* file. Now the text *is* translated.

(And indeed in Xcode 6, localization is easier than ever, because all your localized material can be exported / imported as a unified *.xliff* file.)

Comment: I set the translation to the attributed text in code, @matt, but it says that `setTitle` expects `NSString` instead of `NSMutableAttributedString ` and then crashes. Ok, may be I did not set attributed text properly. I try again and I post some code in my question, 10x.

Comment: Hi @new2ios. Please read my latest edit on my answer. It answers the part about `setTitle`.

Comment: I just try to tell that I read the edit after I upload comment, 10x again for quick response.